# Как передать объект класса в потоке?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть 2-а класса: `public class GUIMain extends JFrame` и `public class Tools extends GUIMain`. В классе "Tools" есть метод `run()` внутри которого следующая конструкция:

```java
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
// ..... code .....
if (table.getRowCount() == 0) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(GUIMain.this,
    "Your Search String was not found. Please try another.", "Search String Not Found",
    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
```

Вопрос: Как передать объект `GUIMain.this` ?

p.s. Нашёл кусочек программы в старой книге по Java и пытаюсь её переписать, разделив один большой класс, содержащий весь код программы (сотни строк), на два удобных класса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данная проблема связана не с многопоточностью как таковой, а со ссылкой на экземпляр внешнего класса из экземпляра внутреннего анонимного класса `Runnable`.  Экземпляр внутреннего класса не может существовать вне экземпляра своего внешнего класса.

Скорей всего, данная реализация метода `run` была скопирована/перенесена из класса `GUIMain` в класс `Tools`, при этом внешний класс изменился и тогда ссылку на внешний класс необходимо соответственно изменить на `Tools.this`:

```java
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Tools.this,
    "Your Search String was not found. Please try another.", 
    "Search String Not Found", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE
);
```

Или же можно отрефакторить код, и определить метод `showOptionPane` *в классе `GUIMain`*, чтобы избавиться от ссылок на конкретный внешний класс.  Также можно использовать лямбду вместо создания анонимной имплементации `Runnable`:

```java
class GUIMain extends JFrame {
    protected void showWarning(String msg, String title) {
        JOptionPane.showOptionPane(this, msg, title, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
}


class Tools extends GUIMain {
    public void run() {
    // ...
        new Thread(() -> {
            //...
            showWarning(
                "Your Search String was not found. Please try another.", 
                "Search String Not Found"
            );
        })
        .start();
    }
}
```